# Import Android Studio project from another PC with different Gradle versions?

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android studio project that wrote in Android Studio version 1.3.2. Now in another PC with Android Studio 2.1.2 I want to import or open that project to it. But when I try, and while opening, error occurred with my Gradle version and want from me to download necessary Gradle version.

But for my reasons, I don't want to download new data with Android studio. how can I manually transfer old PC Gradle to new one? or is there simpler way to resolve that?

Answer (score 7):

Method: 1

Try "`File` -> `New` -> `Import Project`"

or Create new project and copy-paste all project files(Java,XML,Resource) except gradle folder.

Method :2

Or After Import file just change 2.1.2 to 1.3.2

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: method 1 is a formal way and try to download. method 2 is not complete and I receive same error again

Answer (score 6):

**Adding local Gradle to projects would be really helpful**

1.Download Gradle http://www.gradle.org/downloads

2.Install

3.Set Gradle home to the install directory like below : [image]

there is sample project check it : https://github.com/foragerr/SO-35302414-local-gradle-plugin

Comment: then there is no problem to change your android studio version or othere things . really really easy ...

Answer (score 5):

Open your app level **build.gradle** file and change the gradle version accordingly like

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

so just change your version from **1.3.2** to **2.1.2**

Answer (score 5):

1.I faced same problem before .Ok you need to copy `.java` file and `.xml` layouts strings,colors,dimen,drawble images and others in old project

2.And create new android project in your new android studio and paste that file into that project that's it

NOTE: Copy only required files only

Answer (score 4):

Try "File -> New -> Import Project" or just create new project and just copy-paste all project files except gradle folder (change gradle version in build.gradle after copy)

Answer (score 3):

You Need To Check This From [Google Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle).

```
Plugin version  Required Gradle version
1.0.0 - 1.1.3   2.2.1 - 2.3
1.2.0 - 1.3.1   2.2.1 - 2.9
1.5.0   2.2.1 - 2.13
2.0.0 - 2.1.2   2.10 - 2.13
2.1.3+  2.14.1+
```

So You Cannot Use Old Gradle Build With new Android Studio Version According to Google.

You Can Use the Older Version of Of Android Studio to Make Your Project Work With the Old Gradle System

**Look in the SDK Manager what is your highest Android SDK Build-tools version, and copy this version number in your project build.gradle file, in the android/buildToolsVersion property The Build Tool Version Propert Should Be Compatible With the Gradle.**

Comment: The first part is useful. However build tools version has nothing to do with a) Gradle version (`gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties`) b) version of Android build plugin for Gradle (`build.gradle`).

Comment: Unrelated: Holy crap, stop capitalizing every first letter. Do You Know How Hard It Is To Read This Stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

2 ways you could choose to give a try, either of them is okay for me:

1.Copy files and make some configurations:

- create a new empty Android project, copy only java source files and layout\drawable\colors\dimens etc but **Not exclude AndroidManifest.xml** files copy into your new project
- override the AndroidManifest.xml's application tag with the content of the old project's(**only** )
- build the new project, you will meet some 'Not Found' errors, modify package names and path of some files until errors disappear
- done!

2.edit some of gradle files:

- modify contents of *"/Users/your_name/your_project_directory/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties(path could be different on windows)"* , notice distributionUrl="something like https://mirrors.somewhere.net/mirror/gradle/**gradle-xx.xx-all.zip**", **xx.xx** determines the version of gradle the project used
- modify contents of "*/Users/your_name/your_project_directory/build.gradle*" and any modules included in your project will have their own build.gradle file, notice the following:

  ```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          mavenCentral()
      }

      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:xx.xx.xx'
      }
  }
  ```

Then change '**com.android.tools.build:gradle:xx.xx.xx**' which determines the **Plugin version** to the version corresponding to the version of '**gradle-xx.xx-all.zip**' which determines the **Gradle version** as @AndroidHacker's post:

```
Plugin version  Required Gradle version
1.0.0 - 1.1.3   2.2.1 - 2.3
1.2.0 - 1.3.1   2.2.1 - 2.9
1.5.0   2.2.1 - 2.13
2.0.0 - 2.1.2   2.10 - 2.13
2.1.3+  2.14.1+
```

- done!

Answer (score 1):

first thanks for your answers. but I finally find the solution to solve this issue without download anything and just with a few changes in versions and files.

1- Open project folder then /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wraper file.
2- In this txt file, change `distributionUrl` value to: `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`
3- Back to Android Studio.In your project's build.gradle file, change `classpath` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2`
4- In your app's build.gradle file, change `buildToolsVersion` to `"23.0.3"`